# Query optimization using foreach?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made 3 different queries ($rs1 , $rs2, $rs3)-- for the IFs. It looks in the db if the specified product has any images assigned to it .

The thing is I don't know how to optimize all this using only 1 query and 1 foreach.

If anyone can help me , here is the code:

```
<?php use_helper("StaticUrl");?>
<?php
$rs1  = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("Product")
                          ->select("photo1")
                          ->where("title = ?", $product)
                          ->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

$rs2  = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("Product")
                          ->select("photo2")
                          ->where("title = ?", $product)
                          ->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

$rs3  = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("Product")
                          ->select("photo3")
                          ->where("title = ?", $product)
                          ->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

                          ?>


<div class="product_image">
    <?php 
      $href = url_for($product->getRouteUrl(ESC_RAW));
      if ($sf_context->getActionName() == 'view')
    {
      $href = static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath('large',ESC_RAW));
    }
    ?>

  <a <?php echo $sf_context->getActionName() == 'view' ? 'class="lightbox"' : ''; ?> href="<?php echo $href;?>" title="<?php echo $product; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath(ESC_RAW)); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product; ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath('large',ESC_RAW)); ?>" id="zoomea<?php echo SITE_ID; ?>" />
  </a>


  <div id="gallery_01" style="position:absolute;">
    <?php if(!empty($rs1['photo1'])){ ?>

  <a href="#" data-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("medium", 1, ESC_RAW)); ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("large", 1, ESC_RAW)); ?>" >
    <img class="zoomab" src="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("small", 1, ESC_RAW)); ?>" width="50" height="60"/>
  </a>
    <?php } 

        if(!empty($rs2['photo2'])){
    ?>
  <a href="#" data-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("medium", 2, ESC_RAW)); ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("large", 2, ESC_RAW)); ?>" >
    <img class="zoomab" src="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("small", 2, ESC_RAW)); ?>" width="50" height="60" />
  </a>

    <?php } 

        if(!empty($rs3['photo3'])){
    ?>

  <a href="#" data-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("medium", 3, ESC_RAW)); ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("large", 3, ESC_RAW)); ?>"  >
    <img class="zoomab" src="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("small", 3, ESC_RAW)); ?>"  width="50" height="60" />
  </a>
<?php } ?>

</div>

</div>

<script src="/js/elevatezoom/jquery.elevatezoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: How about `->select("photo1,photo2,photo3")`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php use_helper("StaticUrl");?>
<?php
$rs1  = Doctrine_Query::create()->from("Product")
                          ->select("photo1,photo2,photo3")
                          ->where("title = ?", $product)
                          ->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
                          ?>


<div class="product_image">
    <?php 
      $href = url_for($product->getRouteUrl(ESC_RAW));
      if ($sf_context->getActionName() == 'view')
    {
      $href = static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath('large',ESC_RAW));
    }
    ?>

  <a <?php echo $sf_context->getActionName() == 'view' ? 'class="lightbox"' : ''; ?> href="<?php echo $href;?>" title="<?php echo $product; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath(ESC_RAW)); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product; ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath('large',ESC_RAW)); ?>" id="zoomea<?php echo SITE_ID; ?>" />
  </a>


  <div id="gallery_01" style="position:absolute;">
    <?php if(!empty($rs1['photo1'])){ ?>

  <a href="#" data-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("medium", 1, ESC_RAW)); ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("large", 1, ESC_RAW)); ?>" >
    <img class="zoomab" src="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("small", 1, ESC_RAW)); ?>" width="50" height="60"/>
  </a>
    <?php } 

        if(!empty($rs1['photo2'])){
    ?>
  <a href="#" data-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("medium", 2, ESC_RAW)); ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("large", 2, ESC_RAW)); ?>" >
    <img class="zoomab" src="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("small", 2, ESC_RAW)); ?>" width="50" height="60" />
  </a>

    <?php } 

        if(!empty($rs1['photo3'])){
    ?>

  <a href="#" data-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("medium", 3, ESC_RAW)); ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("large", 3, ESC_RAW)); ?>"  >
    <img class="zoomab" src="<?php echo  static_url_for($product->generatePhotoPath("small", 3, ESC_RAW)); ?>"  width="50" height="60" />
  </a>
<?php } ?>

</div>

</div>

<script src="/js/elevatezoom/jquery.elevatezoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```